# Is it really necessary for Euler's characteristic to be in $\Bbb Z$?

Tags: general-topology

I was just wondering, Euler's Characteristic as defined by $\equiv V-E+F$ can take on many values. for example it is equal to $2$ for polyhedra who are homeomorphic to $S^2$, to $0$ for those who are homeomorphic to a torus, and $-2$ for those who are homeomorphic to a torus of genus 2, ...etc

of course all these values are in $\Bbb Z$, but is it really necessary? could we possibly have a shape for which its $\chi$ is $2.3$ or $\pi$? could we define the # of edges to be something like $3.3$ or $2\pi$? (just like we could have a non natural number as the dimension)

Comment: If you can figure out how to make $\pi$ and $3,3$ counting numbers, more power to you.

Comment: why the close vote?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there are various generalizations of Euler characteristic which allow strange values - for instance, the Euler characteristic of a fractal (http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/mana.200410471/asset/152_ftp.pdf?v=1&t=ijvwf5mo&s=6616d453a47d4106b783bb8f7fd733478d57bf7f) or of an arbitrary category (http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~tl/swansea/bmcnotes.pdf).

As in all such cases, a lot of work is involved in (a) coming up with the right generalization and (b) arguing that it is still "of the same species" as the classical Euler characteristic.

This is not something I know a ton about, but hopefully this helps!

Comment: Another useful link that discusses various notions of "Euler characteristic": https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Euler+characteristic

Comment: thanks for your answer, i'll be sure to digest those things when i learn more

Answer (score 0):

Euler's characteristic is the finite part of the numerocity of a set. As such, in its generalizations it can be non-integer.

Such cases include

- When a set has non-integer (fuzzy) indicator function, that is, some points may be partly-included in the set. For instance, naturally Euler characteristic of a set consisting of one half-included point is 1/2.
- In negative dimension (e.g. in infinite lattices) Euler characteristic depends on the position of the lattice. For instance, Euler characteristic of the set of positive natural numbers is $-1/2$, while if we include $0$, it is $1/2$.